# Why should I not turn certain object references into an object variable? What are the guidelines?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Inside my loop (see code below), why should I NOT turn the `ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` reference into a `Range` object variable? (Based on good coding habits, are we not supposed to turn all Range, Worksheet, and Workbook object references into object variables? Regardless if they are used once or many times?)

I did try it with success but I have this feeling I shouldn't but I don't know exactly why which leads me to ask for specific reasons.

```
Sub FormatAllFormulas()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsc As Sheets

    Set wsc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each ws In wsc
        With ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) 
            .Style = "Currency"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = 4908260
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion. Though in this case you almost certainly should (IMO!) use an object variable because it will make the error handling cleaner.

Comment: The only difference it makes may be the readability of the code. Code that is easier to read is better maintainable and leads into less errors. Sometimes it's better to keep the code short. Sometimes it's better to write a bit more for better understanding. Depends on you.

Answer (score 2):

You ***are*** getting a reference to a `Range` variable - it is just held by the `With` block itself.  [5.4.2.21](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199337.aspx) of the language specification explains:

> The With block variable is classified as a variable and has the same
>   declared type as <expression>.

At runtime, this is what happens:

> If the value type of the evaluated expression is a class, it is
>   **Set**-assigned to an anonymous *With* block variable. Then,
>   <statement-block> is executed. After <statement-block> executes,
>   **Nothing** is assigned to the anonymous *With block variable*.

Functionally, this code from your example...

> ```
> For Each ws In wsc
>     With ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) 
>         .Style = "Currency"
>         .Font.Bold = True
>         .Interior.Color = 4908260
>     End With
> Next ws
> ```

...is exactly the same as this:

```
For Each ws In wsc
    Dim WithBlockVariable As Range
    Set WithBlockVariable = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    WithBlockVariable.Style = "Currency"
    WithBlockVariable.Font.Bold = True
    WithBlockVariable.Interior.Color = 4908260
    Set WithBlockVariable = Nothing
Next ws
```

---

As far as which you should use, that's pretty much a judgement call. As pointed out in the comments, the `With` block can be much more readable that a local variable. The other consideration is that since the reference is implicit, you can't accidentally use it after the `With` block exits. This can be important in your example specifically, because declared variables always have procedure scope. That means in the expanded example, you could use `WithBlockVariable` *outside the loop*. So, if you don't *intend* to use it outside the block, you might as well make it ***impossible*** to use outside the block.

---

One last thing to note (and this is where people can get into performance problems) is that `With` blocks can save de-referencing operations if you find yourself repeatedly using more than one `.` in expressions. For example, if you're setting more than one of the properties on the `Font`:

```
With ws.Cells(1, 1)
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = vbRed
    .Font.Italic = True
End With
```

In this case, there's absolutely no reason to get an explicit reference to the `Font`, but notice that you're repeatedly calling the `Range.Font` property. This is always better:

```
With ws.Cells(1, 1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Color = vbRed
    .Italic = True
End With
```